# how to rename file before/after upload

Tags: 8, files

I want to rename an up-loaded file. I have the following code. I have defined a submit handler to do so.

```
function example_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($form_state->hasFileElement()) {

        $video_file_file_array = $form_state->getValue('field_video_file');        
        if (is_array($video_file_file_array)) {
            if (isset($video_file_file_array[0])) {
                $video_file_file_id = $video_file_file_array[0]['fids'][0];
                if($video_file_file_id){
                    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($video_file_file_id);
                    $file->set('filename', 'something');
                    $file->save();

                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working. Is there any other way.

Comment: Did you debug this at all?

Comment: @Kevin, the form id that I had the condition for was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation should work. I suspect that for some or other reason the execution just doesn't pass all the conditions you have there which looks a bit weird.
Here is an example from my project:

```
$fid = $form_state->getValue(['field_video_file', 0]);
if (!$form_state->getErrors() && !empty($fid)) {
  try {
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
    $file->setFilename('smth');
    $file->save();
  }
  catch (\Exception $e) {
    watchdog_exception('myerror', $e);
  }
}
```

Comment: This changes the file name in database. Can we rename the actual file before saving it in public directory.

Comment: @Amit I think you need to make usage of "setFileUri" method. Check the core for usage examples.

Answer (score 4):

Renaming file entity in Drupal 8 can be achieved like this:

```
    $file = File::load($file_target_id);
    $new_filename = "filename.png";
    $stream_wrapper = \Drupal::service('file_system')->uriScheme($file->getFileUri());
    $new_filename_uri = "{$stream_wrapper}://{$new_filename}";
    file_move($file, $new_filename_uri);
```

As you can see in this example Drupal `file_move` function is used here which takes care of everything. You only need to know file `target_id` which is the file `fid`.

Comment: This is the way to go. Drupal 9 deprecated \Drupal::service('file_system')->uriScheme so in D9 use this instead:
$stream_wrapper = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getScheme($file->getFileUri());

Comment: Also, file_move is also deprecated. Use the function "move" from Drupal\file\FileRepositoryInterface (with dependency injection).

Answer (score 1):

I had to allow users to upload a file then rename it and erase existing with same name. In a way to have always only on file on the folder which always have the same path.

I try `$file->setFilename` and `$file->setFileUri` but these only change the name and url for Drupal (in database) but not the real file (on the server) name. 
That's why I had to add a specific piece of code to rename it using drupal/php function.

Maybe I should not have to do it because of bad configuration but it works for me.

```
// In this variable you will have file entity 
$file = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')
    ->load($form_state->getValue('csv_file')[0]);
if (!$file)
  return;

$exUri  = explode('/', $file->getFileUri());
array_pop($exUri);
$rename = file_unmanaged_move($file->getFileUri(), implode('/', $exUri) . '/' . self::FILE_NAME . '.csv', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

if ($rename) { ... }
```

If you also want to change the file uri and name to let Drupal know it, just add these lines :

```
$file->setFilename(self::FILE_NAME);
$file->setFileUri(self::FILE_URI . self::FILE_NAME . '.csv');
$file->save();
```

In my case I had no needs for that.